# VB.NET connecting to oracle database file not found exception

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I'm trying to connect to my oracle database with vb but I couldn't make it work , I get a file not found exception .I've been trying for so long and I feel so desperate .
I downloaded odp(which apparently is not needed) added a reference on my project to oracle and imported  Oracle.DataAccess.Client .
here is the complete code :

```
Imports System.Data
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client ' ODP.NET Oracle managed provider
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Types
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=ORACLE;User Id=SYSTEM;Password=pass123;"
        Dim conn As New OracleConnection(oradb)
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "select customer_id from customers where customer_id = 10"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        dr.Read()
        Label1.Text = dr.Item("department_name")
        conn.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

also I get 2  exceptions when adding the reference:

> Warning 1 There is a difference between the project processor
>   architecture being generated "x86" and the reference processor
>   architecture "Oracle.DataAccess, Version = 2.112.2.0, Culture =
>   neutral, PublicKeyToken = 89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture =
>   AMD64 "," AMD64 ". This difference can lead to runtime problems.
>   Please change the target processor architecture of your project using
>   the configuration manager to align the processor architectures between
>   your project and references, or take a dependency on the references
>   with processor architecture corresponding to the target processor
>   architecture of your project. OraWinApp

and

> Avertissement 2   Problème possible détecté pendant la génération de
>   l'assembly 'OraWinApp' : L'assembly référencé 'Oracle.DataAccess.dll'
>   cible un processeur différent OraWinApp

I would really appreciate any help thanks in advance  ^_^.

Comment: on which line do you get the File Not Found?

Comment: I dont know about the line the message says
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version = 2.112.2.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The specified file was not found.

Comment: `Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client` is not the ODP.NET Oracle managed provider. It must be `Imports Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` for ODP.NET Oracle managed provider.

Comment: Architecture of `Oracle.DataAccess` (seems to be 64 bit) must be the same as your local Oracle client and must be the same as your compile target - unless you use the ODP.NET Oracle managed provider.

Comment: Imports Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client gets underlined and does not work also what do I need to use the Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client ? I created the database using the 'run SQL command line'  
also I didn't find the option for making the project run on 64 bit :S